# Should I edit another answer which states my answer is incorrect, after I have corrected my answer?

Tags: discussion

I had posted an answer two years ago which was accepted, but soon became outdated.

Some other user then posted an answer which is actually correct, but the answer states my answer is incorrect.

However now that I know my answer is accepted and need to reflect the right information, I have edited it with the correct information.

Is it considered wrong to edit the other answer just to remove that statement which says my answer is incorrect?

Comment: Probably, you should leave a comment on that answer instead

Comment: @paper1111.. That user doesn't look very active.. Last time he saw SO was 4 months ago

Comment: No.  Blatantly copying somebody else's answer is very problematic, plagiarism is taken pretty seriously here.  You should make it obvious that you modified your solution, a link to the other answer and the answerer's profile is required by the license.  Keeping the original solution around tends to be wise, not everybody jumps on the next-best-thing.  The need to mess with the other answer now automatically disappears.

Comment: @HansPassant the OP didn't mention directly copying the other answer

Comment: As a SO user when I find a question/answer, I always keep in mind the date because it's relevant to the versions and practices that where current at that time. You can edit your answer and point out on which version it's working a put a link to the other answer (if you think it's correct nowadays).

Answer (score 24):

According to the [help center on editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) (emphasis mine):

> Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and **up-to-date**

As you updated your own answer already, the other answer is not up-to-date as it says that your answer is not up-to-date (but is now), so you can edit it actually.

However, you may want to leave a comment, and if you get no response in the following days, edit the answer instead of editing it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Hans Passant offered what basically amounts to an answer in his comment. I'm elevating (some of) it to a proper answer here:

*No, do not edit the other answer.*

When you edit your own answer to bring it up to date, make it obvious that you've done so. If, in the process of updating your answer, you've incorporated information from someone else's answer (especially if you updated your answer *because* of that other answer), also make it clear that you've done so, including providing a link to the other answer and mentioning the answerer's user profile.

It shouldn't be necessary to alter the other answer at all, but if you want to leave a comment to point out that your answer is now up-to-date, that's fine.